# Override date when adding items to TFS using the APIs

Tags: tfs

I'm in the process of migrating some source code from an in-house system over to TFS 2015. I'm using the APIs via Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client etc libraries.

Ideally I would like to also import the history of each item including who made the change and when.

The workspace.CheckIn method allows me to specify the "author" who made the change,  but I don't think it's possible to supply the when.

Does anyone know if's it possible to "back-date" a checkin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change CreatedDate of a changeset. In fact you should not be doing this in the first place.

Even if you manage to change somehow then you will **loose the track of when you really created/check in the changeset on TFS**.

If you are upgrading older TFS to TFS2015. Which is a full data transfer. TFS sever will also include the back-date changeset. However you are using an in-house system, just the same as checking in code from local development.

So you may have to manually manage the source control history of your in-house system, such as import to a Excel.

Comment: I expected this might be the case - thank you anyway.